# To recipients keep getting added on subsequent emails in FluentEmail

Tags: c#, email, .net-5

I'm using [FluentEmail](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail) to send emails, everything is working well except there's this issue where the *'To'* recipients keep getting added for every subsequent email.

For eg: If it's sending emails to `someone@abc.com`:

1. The first time the `SendEmailAsync` method is called, it sends email to: `someone@abc.com`

   [image]
2. The second time the `SendEmailAsync` method is called, it sends email to: `someone@abc.com;someone@abc.com`

   [image]
3. The third time the `SendEmailAsync` method is called, it sends email to:
   `someone@abc.com;someone@abc.com;someone@abc.com`

   [image]

and so on. It gets *really long* after some time.

My code looks like this:

`ConfigureServices` method:

```
// Set email service using FluentEmail
services.AddFluentEmail("myapp@goodboi.com")
        .AddRazorRenderer(@$"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/Views/")
        .AddSmtpSender("smtp.somecompanyname.com", 25)
        .AddSmtpSender(new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient() { });
```

Now the email service looks like this:

```
public class FluentEmailService : IFluentEmailService
{
    private readonly IFluentEmail _fluentEmail;
    private readonly ILogger<FluentEmailService> _logger;
    public FluentEmailService(ILogger<FluentEmailService> logger, IFluentEmail fluentEmail)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _fluentEmail = fluentEmail;
    }

    public async Task<SendResponse> SendEmailAsync<TModel>(string subject, string razorTemplatePath, TModel model, string semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipients)
    {
        var sendResponse = await _fluentEmail
                        .To(semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipients)
                        .Subject(subject)
                        .UsingTemplateFromFile(razorTemplatePath, model)
                        .SendAsync();
        return sendResponse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `IFluentEmailFactory` instead of `IFluentEmail` solved the issue for me.

Now the email service looks like this:

```
public class FluentEmailService : IFluentEmailService
{
    private readonly IFluentEmailFactory _fluentEmailFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<FluentEmailService> _logger;
    public FluentEmailService(ILogger<FluentEmailService> logger, IFluentEmailFactory fluentEmailFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _fluentEmailFactory = fluentEmailFactory;
    }

    public async Task<SendResponse> SendEmailAsync<TModel>(string subject, string razorTemplatePath, TModel model, string semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipients)
    {
        var sendResponse = await _fluentEmailFactory
                        .Create()
                        .To(semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipients)
                        .Subject(subject)
                        .UsingTemplateFromFile(razorTemplatePath, model)
                        .SendAsync();
        return sendResponse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be suggested as a temporary solution. But better use IFluentEmailFactory.

```
public async Task<SendResponse> SendEmailAsync<TModel>(string subject, string razorTemplatePath, TModel model, string semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipients)
    {
        // Added this line
        _fluentEmail.Data.ToAddresses = new List<Address>();

        var sendResponse = await _fluentEmail
                        .To(semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipients)
                        .Subject(subject)
                        .UsingTemplateFromFile(razorTemplatePath, model)
                        .SendAsync();
        return sendResponse;
    }
```